# Problems with permission on a administrator user on a AZURE VM WINDOWS 10

Tags: azure, windows-10, virtual-machine

I have a administrator user on AZURE, i managed to log in to my simple WINDOWS 10 GEN2 VM, but when i need to install some application i'm having problems with permission.

See the picture, a simple install:

[image]

And my application that need to acess a file in RegKey giving me some errors, like i'm not a full admnistrator from this VM.

[image]

What i must do to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi,  I think this is more suitable for SuperUser, as SO is for programming questions, which this isn't.

Comment: hello @wavrik, may i know how you are signing in to the VM , using user of azure active directory or the administrator user name password that you have mentioned while creating the VM?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MTuser name that i create on creating the VM